# Get per process user and system CPU time on OSX via command line?

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

I am familiar with `pidstat` command that gives separate user and system CPU per process on Linux:

```
$ sudo pidstat -p 3162
Linux 4.18.0-13-generic (ubi)   26.12.2018  _x86_64_    (1 CPU)

11:26:13      UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest   %wait    %CPU   CPU  Command
11:26:13     1000      3162    0.24    0.04    0.00    0.12    0.28     0  emacs
```

How can I accomplish the same on Mac OSX?

`top` on OSX gives these values but only on the machine level and not per process. For processes, it seems to give only total CPU used

```
Load Avg: 3.26, 3.02, 3.01  CPU usage: 3.13% user, 5.69% sys, 91.16% idle  SharedLibs: 169M resident, 44M data, 11M

PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS
97229  powerlogd    0.0  00:00.45 2     1    51    1160K  16K    1744K  97229 1     sleeping *1[1]
```

Per process, it shows only the total cpu percentage and not the user and system split.
How do I get both user and system time?

Comment: you already have the answer the % split CPU is in coulomb 15 &16. So you have the Total and the split

Answer (score 2):

Not sure the information you are looking for is accessible so easily. You could try `ps`

```
$ ps -p 407 -o pid,time,utime,etime,comm
  PID      TIME     UTIME     ELAPSED COMM
  407   2:08.23   1:46.36 11-17:10:27 /Applications/Aquamacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Aquamacs
```

and calculate the system time (TIME - UTIME) and the percentages. This is just the total since the process started though, not an ongoing sampling.

Comment: More info from `man ps`: **`etime`**: `elapsed running time`; **`time`** `:accumulated CPU time, user + system (alias cputime)`; **`utime:`** `user CPU time (alias putime)`

Answer (score -1):

You were close with Top command,

now try `Top -A`

and it will show you this per Process (PID)

[image]

or try this `top -F -R -o cpu`

All the possible Top command options

[image]

While `Top` is running press `o` (and/or Capital O) then use any of the listed options with it to modify what and how is it displayed in real time.

Comment: `-A` gives me an invalid syntax on HighSierra. `top` still displays the total cpu  per process and not the user and system separately unless I missed something here.

Comment: I just tried the `top -a` on High Sierran and it does work

Comment: It shows CPU usage by user

Comment: May I wasn't very clear, `top` shows the process total cpu time and not the split. I need both user and system time. Updated the question too

Comment: OK, Total CPU is in 3d coulomb, the split is %CPU_me and %CPU_others in coulomb 15 &16

Comment: I read the man page and they definitely don't mention anything about system time or necessarily the split. `cpu_me` - CPU time charged to me by other processes while `cpu_others` says CPU time charged to other processes by me.  Care to explain with some links on what those mean?

Comment: sorry, by now I am not sure to now what you want or what the question is, however I believe the display I gave you shows it all -Top command has to offer.

Answer (score -1):

The solution for MAC is :

```
top -a -n20 | awk 'FNR>=11 && FNR<=31{print $0};FNR==31{exit}' > cpustat.txt
```

Comment: What does this do and how does it solve the question asked in the question?